# Controlling or Predicting JVM heap size

Tags: java, jvm, spring-data-jpa, heap-memory

I have a Spring based Java web application which handles big data with help of Mongo DB. One functionality of my application is to export large amount of data to xls/csv. I have around 5.5 million records in db and I want to export them to xls. The max no of rows supported by single xls file is around 1 million. Hence initially I planned to create 5-6 files with 1 million records each.

However after extracting data from database, I am getting out of memory exception while handling large no of Java Objects that get created. Each this object will correspond to one row in xls.

Since This app can be installed on different servers with different memory sizes. I want to predict what is safe no of objects which I can export to excel file without causing out of memory exception. In short I want to implement below mentioned formula :

```
No of objects to be exported = (Heap space available - some Buffer)/ Size occupied by single obejct
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with below a way to find the number of objects.

1) find the **Heap space available** using **Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()** as below :

```
long freeMemory=Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

2) define a class to get Size of single object. using java's [Intrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) interface like below:

```
public class InstrumentationAgent { //create a **InstrumentationAgent** class

      private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

      public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        instrumentation = inst;
      }

      public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
      }
    }
```

**Add class to manifest file:**

```
  Premain-class: some.package.InstrumentationAgent // Add the **InstrumentationAgent** class to your manifest file
```

3) And now define buffer size and get the number of objects as below:

```
long freeMemory=Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
long singleObjectSize=InstrumentationAgent.getObjectSize(new Object());
int numberOfObject= (int)((freeMemory-defaultBufferSize)/singleObjectSize);
```

Comment: Thanks Raju! This helped me to a large extent.

Comment: Note: the free memory size is only meaningful after a full GC. Before then it will be lower as there are objects which could be cleaned up but haven't been as a GC hasn't run.